# What are XHTML/XML QNames?

Tags: xml, xhtml

I was wondering what are the xml qnames are they pre-defined name, is there a list of them or can I make my own name?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QName ... first link on a google search.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you may make up your own name. A typical way to create a QName and instantiate a Service in Java would be:

```
QName serviceName = new QName("http://www.xmethods.net/sd/BNQuoteService.wsdl","BNQuoteService");
Service service = Service.create(url, serviceName);
```

The QName line came from this [IBM site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipjaxrpc/).

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, the qname is the global name in your tag, weither prefix:localname if a namespace is defined in your document, or just localname if not.